Does TimescaleDB/PostgreSQL work well with Azure Disk backup?
I'm investigating improvements to a self-hosted TimescaleDB in Microsoft Azure. We have Timescale running in an AKS cluster, with a Standard SSD Azure Disk mounted as its persistent storage. Thus far we've used pg_dump for our backup strategy, but we're dissatisfied with its running time and the dump size.
Our research suggests that Azure Disk backup may be appropriate for our use case. Microsoft claims that Azure Disk backup is useful when "invoking freeze and thaw on Linux virtual machines to get application-consistent backup puts undue overhead on production workload availability. To the best of our understanding, that is indeed how one would build TimescaleDB filesystem backups from the ground up.
The PostgreSQL documentation also notes that "we can combine a file-system-level backup with backup of the WAL files...We do not need a perfectly consistent file system backup as the starting point." This also bodes well, but it is perhaps a bit unclear how far from "perfectly consistent" we can reasonably get before things break.
Is Azure Disk backup the sort of atomic operation that would help prevent an inconsistent/corrupted database? Has anyone tried this approach before? If it didn't work - why not, and what did?

I work as a Timescaledb Community manager, and I often answer questions across all kinds of topics, and I never see any reporting regarding this topic. Did you got any error from your case?

Not an error per se - but using pg_dump has simply not served us well. The process takes hours to complete and the results are so gigantic no developer can work with them. NB our TimescaleDB instance is storing terabytes of data and constantly ingesting.
